# Django template - checkbox did not react when is select

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, checkbox

I have app in django and I updated my model:

```
is_promoted_post = models.BooleanField(default=False)
promoted_from = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
promoted_to = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
promoted_budget = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=True, null=True)
```

My goals are the appearance of the remaining fields when the `is_promoted_post` field is selected.

In template I have:

```
<h2>Promoted post</h2>
  <label>Promoted post?</label>
    {{ form.is_promoted_post }}
    <br><br>

  <label>Promoted date from</label>
    {{ form.promoted_from }}

  <label>Promoted date to</label>
    {{ form.promoted_to }}

  <label>Promoted budget</label>
    {{ form.promoted_budget }}
```

When I use Firebug to get more details about `is_promoted_post` I get:

```
<input checked="checked" id="id_is_promoted_post" name="is_promoted_post" type="checkbox">
```

I tried do start my js code but code did not respond when I selected checkbox without save model.

My js code:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
      if ($('input#id_is_promoted_post').prop('checked')) {
        alert('Test test');
        }
    });
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if you want trigger `check/uncheck`

```
$('#id_is_promoted_post').change(function() {
    if(this.checked) {
        alert("checked")
        return false;
    }
    alert("unchecked")       
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if ($('#id_is_promoted_post').prop('checked')) {
    alert('Test test');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#id_is_promoted_post').is(':checked')` will return `true` if the `checkbox` gets checked or `false` differently.
So you can also try with the following code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  if ($('#id_is_promoted_post').is(':checked')) {
    alert('Test test');
    }
});
```